# How can I change the directory of the .condarc file?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I need to be able to change the location Anaconda looks at for the `.condarc` file. The drive it's trying to access doesn't exist anymore and that's causing practically every conda command to fail. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda. I also tried `conda config --file C:\.condarc`

This has been surprisingly difficult to search for - any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: I forgot to mention - it's the 64-bit Windows version

Comment: [Using the .condarc conda configuration file](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html)

Comment: I found that, thanks, but it doesn't address changing the directory of the .condarc file itself (unless I'm overlooking something). A fresh conda install for me is still looking in the wrong place.

Comment: **The .condarc file is not included by default, but it is automatically created in your home directory the first time you run the conda config command.** Seems pretty specific.  I'm just guessing, based upon the docs.

Comment: Running `conda config` results in this error: `CondaError: Cannot write to condarc file at H:\.condarc
Caused by FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')` ... in other words, the guidance they have there doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: I can even make a new `.condarc` file with `conda config --file C:\.condarc` and it creates the almost blank file in the right location. But anaconda is still looking for the nonexistent `H:\.condarc` file location

Comment: Try **A .condarc file may also be located in the root environment, in which case it overrides any in the home directory**.  I think this means **root of anaconda installation**.

Comment: Also, in the anaconda prompt, `conda info` may display `user config file` and `populated config files`

Comment: I tried `conda activate root` and `conda config --system` and `conda config --env`, all of which did something... and there is indeed a `.condarc` file in the main conda install folder... but when I try and update conda itself or create a new environment, I get the same error. Doing `conda info` reveals that it's still looking for the `H:\.condarc` file...

Comment: Also, are you the system admin?  When you installed, did you choose the option to install for `all users`?

Comment: I bet `format` and `reinstall` windows will resolve the issue.  :)

Comment: I am the local admin, but I didn't install as admin and I believe I told it to just install for me (whatever the default is). Yes, I'm sure blowing Windows away and starting over would do it... haha

Comment: There's one more option I just thought of.  Is there a `mklink` to the other location?  That's a windows symbolic link.

Comment: dir /AL /S C:\  from https://superuser.com/questions/496092/view-a-list-of-symbolic-links-on-system shows how to search for symbolic links

Comment: No, there aren't any of those relating to conda. I did a text search of all files in the conda directory to look for H:, but nothing of interest turned up

Comment: Do you have any Windows environment variables that still point to `H:`?

Comment: I think that might be it! In the environment variables, HOME is set to %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% where %HOMEDRIVE% is set to H: and %HOMEPATH% is set to \ ... those aren't listed in the environment variables though. How do I set these permanently if they're not environment variables like everything else?

Answer (score 2):

I *finally* got a working solution. It doesn't actually change the location that conda looks to find the `.condarc` file, but it does work.

Many thanks to nekomatic for the idea!

The `%HOME%` environment variable was set to `H:\` and was being used to find the `.condarc` file. Though it's probably possible to change the way those variables are set. I instead just mapped my C: drive to H: by assigning H: to `\\localhost\C$\`

Now.. finally... conda can install things, make environments, etc. I hope this post helps someone else avoid all this frustration.

Comment: You saved me! Thanks a lot. I agree that the lack of documentation for such an inconvenient bug is very high!

Comment: On linux I changed my home folder location ```HOME=/newpath/``` and then ran ```source /newpath/miniconda3/bin/activate``` and was able to see that the condarc path changed when I called ```conda info```

Comment: Any of the above solution work for me. Conda is still looking for the .condarc file in my C:\Users\my_name directory for the file.

I created the HOME environment variable pointing to an other location (hardcoded, not dependent on other env var), where the .condarc is located but it does not work.

Comment: I am working in gitbash, I don't know if that matters

Answer (score 0):

The [answer from @BurntUmber](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58184677/758174) is great if, like me, you'd like to run `conda` with a temporary `.condarc` (without messing up the regular `~/.condarc`), for example to temporarily set certain channels:

```sh
d=$(mktemp -d tmp-conda-config.XXXX)
cat > $d/.condarc <<EOF
channels:
  - s3://mybucket/packages/conda/nightly
  - s3://mybucket/packages/conda/main
  - defaults
channel_priority: true
EOF
rsync -az ~/.aws $d/
HOME=$d conda env create --force -n myenv -f environment.yml
```

**Update**

After (re-)reading [Conda Configuration Engine for Power Users](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/conda-configuration-engine-power-users), the above can be achieved more simply by using `CONDARC`:

```sh
f=$(mktemp condarc-XXXX)
cat > $f << EOF
channels:
  - s3://mybucket/packages/conda/nightly
  - s3://mybucket/packages/conda/main
  - defaults
channel_priority: true
EOF

CONDARC=$f conda env create --force -n myenv -f environment.yml
```